# How to set up an email notification if a user gets a new role?

Tags: 7, users, emails

I'm on d7. I want to notify users if they have received a new role. Any suggestions on how can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this is for manually promoting a user. I would try creating a rule using the Rules module for modifying the role and sending a mail to the user about his/her new role on the site.

I'm still learning how to use Rules, so I won't be able to give you a detailed recipe here, but after watching the excellent [Rules screencast series at the NodeOne site](http://dev.nodeone.se/node/634), you might be able to do this quickly without making a custom module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "[Role change Notify](https://drupal.org/project/role_change_notify)" module. But this module only sending one and the same email content to the user regardless of which new role assigned. You can't send different emails to different user based on the different role assigned.

I think a better way is to use Rules module to achieve. But no easy event can achieve this at the moment. Im still figuring out how to code it with Rules. Any new findings please let us know. Thanks.